# Is there a limit to the amount of charge that could be stored in any system as a result of the charge particles repelling each other?

Tags: capacitor

Is there a limit to the amount of charge that could be stored in any system as a result of the charge particles repelling each other?

Comment: I think the [corona discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge) effect comes from trying to go above the limit, without proper insulation.

Comment: Are you asking in terms of practical electrical engineering, or in terms of fundamental physics? In the latter case, you'd be better off asking in [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There might be physical limits hit when you have a very high charge density in a small space, but there are much more practical problems: how do you get the charge to stay there?

In the simple model of a capacitor, there are two plates on which a charge is stored. Between the two is some insulating material, usually a *dielectric* to increase performance of the capacitor, but it's possible to have air or vacuum capacitors too. The limit on how much charge can be stored is determined by the *breakdown voltage* between the plates, which depends on how good the insulator is.